# exception handling and string converter

Tags: java, type-conversion, numberformatexception

Below is my coding, it is still unfinished,

```
import java.lang.* ;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pbtwashing
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String satu,dua,tiga,empat,weightrange,message,minus,rinse,spin,d,comp;
        int x,min;
        double a;
        minus="\t\t  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------";
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\t\t  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\t\t|                            Welcome To PBU Laundry !                          |");
        System.out.println("\t\t|                       There are 4 type of wash you can choose.               |");
        System.out.println("\t\t| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------|");
        System.out.println("\t\t| a-Normal Wash   |  a. 2kg == 30 Mins | b. 3kg == 40 Mins | c. 5kg == 50 Mins |");
        System.out.println("\t\t|                 |                                                            |");
        System.out.println("\t\t| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------|");
        System.out.println("\t\t| b-Hard Wash     |  a. 2kg == 40 Mins | b. 3kg == 50 Mins | c. 5kg == 60 Mins |");
        System.out.println("\t\t|                 |                                                            |");
        System.out.println("\t\t| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------|");
        System.out.println("\t\t| c-Delicate Wash |  a. 2kg == 30 Mins | b. 3kg == 40 Mins | c. 5kg == 50 Mins |");
        System.out.println("\t\t|                 |       (Rinse after wash step will take extra 3 seconds)    |");
        System.out.println("\t\t| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------|");
        System.out.println("\t\t| d-Speed Wash    |  a. 2kg == 30 Mins | b. 3kg == 40 Mins                     |");
        System.out.println("\t\t|                 |       (Cloths weight cannot more than 3kg)                 |");
        System.out.println("\t\t  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("\t\t\n\n                                      Please choose between (1-4) : ");

        min=0;
        d="\n\n\t\t\tdone\n\n";
        message="\n\n\t\t\tStep 1 : Washing......\n\n";
        rinse="\n\n\t\t\tStep 2 : Rinsing......\n\n";
        spin="\n\n\t\t\tStep 3 : Spining......\n\n";
        comp="\n\n\t\t\tyour laundry is now complete\n\n\t\t\tminutes taken for laundry to complete is : " ;
        satu="Normal Wash";
        dua="Hard Wash";
        tiga="Delicate Wash";
        empat="Speed Wash";
        weightrange ="  Please choose your cloth weight range";

        x = in.nextInt();
        if (x == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t" + satu + " has been Chosen." + "\n" +minus);
            System.out.print("\t\t\t" + weightrange + " (2kg/3kg/5kg) : ");

            min=in.nextInt();
            switch (min)
            {
                case 2:
                    System.out.println(minus);
                    slowPrint(message, 100);
                    tenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint1(rinse, 100);
                    tenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint2(spin, 100);
                    tenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint4(comp,100);
                    a=30;
                    System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println(minus);
                    slowPrint(message, 100);
                    thirteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint1(rinse, 100);
                    thirteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint2(spin, 100);
                    thirteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint4(comp,100);
                    a=40;
                    System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println(minus);
                    slowPrint(message, 100);
                    sixteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint1(rinse, 100);
                    sixteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint2(spin, 100);
                    sixteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint4(comp,100);
                    a=50;
                    System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tWrong Input ");

            }
        }
        else if (x == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t" + dua + " has been Chosen." + "\n" +minus);
            System.out.print("\t\t\t" + weightrange + " (2kg/3kg/5kg) : ");
            min = in.nextInt();

            switch (min)
            {
                case 2:
                    System.out.println(minus);
                    slowPrint(message, 100);
                    thirteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint1(rinse, 100);
                    thirteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint2(spin, 100);
                    thirteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint4(comp,100);
                    a=30;
                    System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println(minus);
                    slowPrint(message, 100);
                    sixteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint1(rinse, 100);
                    sixteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint2(spin, 100);
                    sixteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint4(comp,100);
                    a=50;
                    System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println(minus);
                    slowPrint(message, 100);
                    twentyminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint1(rinse, 100);
                    twentyminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint2(spin, 100);
                    twentyminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint4(comp,100);
                    a=60;
                    System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tWrong Input ");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (x == 3)
        { 
            System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t" + tiga + " has been Chosen." + "\n" +minus);
            System.out.print("\t\t\t" + weightrange + " (2kg/3kg/5kg) : ");

            min=in.nextInt();

            switch (min)
            {
                case 2:
                    System.out.println(minus);
                    slowPrint(message, 100);
                    tenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint1(rinse, 100);
                    tenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint2(spin, 100);
                    tenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint4(comp,100);
                    a=30;
                    System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println(minus);
                    slowPrint(message, 100);
                    thirteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint1(rinse, 100);
                    thirteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint2(spin, 100);
                    thirteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint4(comp,100);
                    a=40;
                    System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println(minus);
                    slowPrint(message, 100);
                    sixteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint1(rinse, 100);
                    sixteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint2(spin, 100);
                    sixteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint4(comp,100);
                    a=50;
                    System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tWrong Input ");
            }
        }
        else if (x == 4)
        {
            System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t" + empat + " has been Chosen." + "\n" +minus);
            System.out.print("\t\t\t" + weightrange + " (2kg/3kg/5kg) : ");
            min=in.nextInt();
            switch (min)
            {
                case 2:
                    System.out.println(minus);
                    slowPrint(message, 100);
                    tenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint1(rinse, 100);
                    tenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint2(spin, 100);
                    tenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint4(comp,100);
                    a=30;
                    System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println(minus);
                    slowPrint(message, 100);
                    thirteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint1(rinse, 100);
                    thirteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint2(spin, 100);
                    thirteenminutes();
                    slowPrint3(d,100);
                    slowPrint4(comp,100);
                    a=40;
                    System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("\n"+minus);
                    System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tWrong Input ");
            }
        }


        else
        {
            System.out.println("\n"+minus);
            System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tWrong Input ");
        }
    }

    static void tenminutes()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println("\t\t\t"+ i + " minutes ");
        }
    }

    static void thirteenminutes()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i <= 13; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println("\t\t\t"+ i + " minutes ");
        }
    }

    static void sixteenminutes()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i <= 16; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println("\t\t\t"+ i + " minutes ");
        }
    }


    static void twentyminutes()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i <= 20; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println("\t\t\t"+ i + " minutes ");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to print each character in a string with a delay (a "typewriter" effect)
     * @param message The string to print
     * @param millisPerChar Milliseconds to take to print each character
     */
    public static void slowPrint(String message, long millisPerChar)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(message.charAt(i));
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(millisPerChar);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Function to print each character in a string with a delay (a "typewriter" effect)
     * @param String The string to print
     * @param millisPerChar Milliseconds to take to print each character
     */
    public static void slowPrint1(String rinse, long millisPerChar)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rinse.length(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(rinse.charAt(i));

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(millisPerChar);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    /**
     * Function to print each character in a string with a delay (a "typewriter" effect)
     * @param spin The string to print
     * @param millisPerChar Milliseconds to take to print each character
     */
    public static void slowPrint2(String spin, long millisPerChar)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < spin.length(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(spin.charAt(i));

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(millisPerChar);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void slowPrint3(String d, long millisPerChar)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < d.length(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(d.charAt(i));

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(millisPerChar);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    public static void slowPrint4(String comp, long millisPerChar)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < comp.length(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(comp.charAt(i));

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(millisPerChar);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me apply `NumberFormatException` at the cloth weight range and it will loop if user doesn't meet the input requirement, also i need to convert a string to primitive data .
i have already tried many times but still cant done . thanks in advance for any help. 
ps/ sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What have you tried, what exactly is going wrong? please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Welcome to Stackoverflow btw!

Comment: tried to use numberexceptionhandling , and change a string into primitive data type. nothing is wrong , i just want to use numberexception handling and change a string into primitive data such as integer.

Comment: you want to throw an exception somewhere? then do it... convert a String to `int`? go ahead... what exactly can we help you with? did you read the link?

Comment: i already done it, but i failed, i already read the link , and done some , but still failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Your code is too long, I didn't read it.

I kinda get what you want to do. You want to keep asking the user for input until the input is valid. I hope I understood you correctly.

One way to do this is, as you have said, using `NumberFormatException`:

```
int userInput;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
    try {
        userInput = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Input Invalid! Try again!");
    }
}
// do stuff with userInput
```

However, it is not recommended to use exceptions as a way of controlling the execution because it takes a lot of time to throw an exception.

Another way of checking whether the input is valid, is using regular expressions:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(<<Regular Expression Here>>);
int userInput;
String userString;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
    userString = scan.nextLine();
    if (pattern.matcher(userString).matches()) {
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Input invalid. Try again!");
    }
}
userInput = Integer.parseInt(userString);
```

See that `<<Regular Expression Here>>` thingy? If you want the user to enter an unsigned integer, replace that with `"\\d+"`. If you want the user to enter a signed integer, replace that with `"[\\+-]?\\d+"`.

Comment: i have tried using your code, and i still failed , probably because i didnt know where to put your code, perhaps you could help me where to attach the code. by the way , the reason i need to use numberformatexception and convert a string to primitive data is because this is my assignment for my project, and my mark will be deducted if i dont use both of them.

Comment: Just replace the piece of your code where you get user input with my code. @ikhwansalihin

Comment: this is how i implement your code http://www.imageno.com/hibkajoj19mspic.html

Comment: Apparently this is caused by the `nextInt` call on a previous line. Just change all the `in.nextInt` calls to `Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine())` @ikhwansalihin

Comment: thanks sweeper ! now all i need to solve is convert a string into primitive data. any string would be fine.

Comment: @ikhwansalihin You have already done that! I don't understand what you're trying to solve. If my answer answered your question, please consider accepting by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: i dont understand what did you mean i already done that. which string i converted into a int? and i will click the checkmark .

Comment: You converted the value returned by `nextLine` to an int by calling `Integer.parseInt`, didn't you? @ikhwansalihin

Comment: sorry about that , i didnt know, since i'am new to java, i thought it would be something like declaring a string and int and convert it like this  string x=num1. but now i understand already . thanks sweeper ! :))

Answer (score -1):

Just try this. Its working as per your requirement. It takes valid input 1,2,3 and treat rest of anything as garbage. It asks user until you give input between 1 and 3.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Number bwn 1 & 3: ");
    boolean isRequired = false;
   int num1 = 0;
    do {
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Retry again with number bwn 1 & 3");
            sc.next();
        }
        num1 = sc.nextInt();
        if(!(num1<4 && num1>0))
        System.out.println("Retry again with number bwn 1 & 3");
    }while (num1 >3 || num1 <=0);
    System.out.println( "The correct choice of the number is " + num1);
}
```

Comment: i understood completely your code and it works just fine , but the problem is that my input needed is 2,3 and 5 . it is not between 1-3 . by the way , the reason i need to use numberformatexception and convert a string to primitive data is because this is my assignment for my project, and my mark will be deducted if i dont use both of them.